# Polymorphic and non-polymorphic associations on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a Log model with a polymorphic association and another association to a User model:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my User model, I have a `has_many` association to the Log model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs
end
```

I want to have another association in the User model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs
  has_many :logs, as: :loggable
end
```

But I imagine that those two associations will conflict each other (I don't know, didn't try)...

So is that the right approach to this problem? Or there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why you need another association to Log?

Comment: I need one association where User is the "actor" and one where User is the "subject". For example: "user1 added a note on contact2" (user1 is the actor) and user2 suspended user1 (user1 is the subject, user2 is the actor)

Comment: You're only logging users or other models as well?

Can't you do this on Logs table (actor_id, subject_id), use  and make scopes on the User model?

Comment: I'm logging multiple models. @Marek Lipka gave the right solutions, where the Log model stays as generic as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about renaming one of your associations like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_logs, class_name: 'Log'
  has_many :logs, as: :loggable
end
```

To fetch all your logs associated with given user, you could set scope on `Log` model like this:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  scope :for_user, lambda { |user|
    where('user_id = :user_id OR (loggable_type = "User" AND loggable_id = :user_id)', user_id: user.id)
  }
end
```

Comment: That's a good idea that I didn't think of, but I would like to get all the logs associated with a User with one command (sorted correctly), if it's possible of course. So if there is a way to name the two associations the same way it would be ideal. Otherwise, I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @AzizLight I edited my answer. I think it's the best way to handle your problem.